# navigaton to page from hub section

Tags: navigation, windows-store-apps

I want my app to move to description page **on click** to **hub section**
but the code isn't working ...

**Here is my xaml** 
,have many section but have declared one..

```
 <Hub Header="Hub"  x:Name="hub" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="420" Width="1500" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,113,-134,0">

        <HubSection x:Name="one"  Header="HubSection 0" Width="330" Height="380"   >


            <HubSection.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Assets/ck.png"/>
            </HubSection.Background>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Hub SectionHeaderClick="Hub_SectionHeaderClick" Padding="40,40,0,0" Name="click">

                </Hub>

            </DataTemplate>

        </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

**Here is my Css**

```
 private void Hub_SectionHeaderClick(object sender, HubSectionHeaderClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(descripton));
    }
```

Comment: How isn't this working? what happens when you click on the section header?

Answer (score 0):

You are using A DataTemplate but this need to be associated to an ItemsControl.

Try this:

```
<Hub Header="Hub"  x:Name="hub" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="420" Width="1500" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,113,-134,0">    
    <HubSection x:Name="one"  Header="HubSection 0" Width="330" Height="380"   Tapped="Hub_SectionHeaderClick">    
        <HubSection.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Assets/ck.png"/>
        </HubSection.Background>    
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Thanks,